# Increment integer at end of string

Tags: php, string

I have a string, "Chicago-Illinos1" and I want to add one to the end of it, so it would be "Chicago-Illinos2".

Note: it could also be Chicago-Illinos10 and I want it to go to Chicago-Illinos11 so I can't do substr.

Any suggested solutions?

Comment: The first thing to consider when you hit a problem like this is should you be doing it in the first place.  So, **why** do you want to do this (there's a good change there's a better/more-efficient/more-maintainable answer...

Comment: Also, you spelled Illinois incorrectly.

Comment: I have my reasons ircmaxell, it would take more then I am allowed in this comment box to explain.

Comment: Evan - lol, I do know that. Thanks

Comment: @Steven I've updated your question to fix some typos and add a more obvious title. In future, I'd recommend spending a little bit more time explaining what you're attempting to achieve and at least checking for rudimentary spelling mistakes. This might seem harsh, but if you can't be bothered to spend time asking a question, why would you expect people to spend time answering it? Incidentally, there are some great hints over on http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: If your data is in a consistent format, i.e. City-StateN where N can be any integer number, you could easily parse it with regular expressions (something like `([^-]*)-([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)`) then build a new string with the incremented number. If your data is *not* consistent, you'll probably have to write a function that goes character-by-character and parses out the number, adds 1 to it, and creates a new string with the new number. I don't have time atm to help with something like that, but later I'll check back in and see if anyone's provided a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match("/(.*?)(\d+)$/","Chicago-Illinos1",$matches);
$newstring = $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
```

(can't try it now but it should work)

Answer (score 12):

Complex solutions for a really simple problem...

```
$str = 'Chicago-Illinos1';
echo $str++; //Chicago-Illinos2
```

If the string ends with a number, it will increment the number (eg: 'abc123'++ = 'abc124').

If the string ends with a letter, the letter will be incremeted (eg: '123abc'++ = '123abd')

Comment: If the number is always present, it's overkill to bloat with regular expressions or other unnecessary functions.  [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) - rudimentary

Comment: Good to know, unfortunately in this case, it would mean turning 'Chicago-Illinos9' into 'Chicago-Illinot0'. So if we want wanting to go to more digits, he would have to start with 'Chicago-Illinos001' or something.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'Chicago-Illinois1';
preg_match('/^([^\d]+)([\d]*?)$/', $string, $match);
$string = $match[1];
$number = $match[2] + 1;

$string .= $number;
```

Tested, works.

Answer (score 1):

explode could do the job aswell

```
<?php
$str="Chicago-Illinos1"; //our original string

$temp=explode("Chicago-Illinos",$str); //making an array of it
$str="Chicago-Illinos".($temp[1]+1); //the text and the number+1
?>
```

Comment: substr would probably be better in this case.

Comment: -1 That's only of use if the non-numeric text is known, which is pretty much the point of the question.

Comment: In the situation described the non-numeric text is known and even though substr is better i only mentioned the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to get the number at the end of a string (for Java it would be *[0-9]+$*), increase it (*int number = Integer.parse(yourNumberAsString) + 1*), and concatenate with Chicago-Illinos (the rest not matched by the regular expression used for finding the number).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` to accomplish this:

```
$name = 'Chicago-Illinos10';
preg_match('/(.*?)(\d+)$/', $name, $match);
$base = $match[1];
$num = $match[2]+1;
print $base.$num;
```

The following will output:

```
Chicago-Illinos11
```

However, if it's possible, I'd suggest placing another delimiting character between the text and number. For example, if you placed a pipe, you could simply do an `explode` and grab the second part of the array. It would be much simpler.

```
$name = 'Chicago-Illinos|1';
$parts = explode('|', $name);
print $parts[0].($parts[1]+1);
```

If string length is a concern (thus the misspelling of Illinois), you could switch to the state abbreviations. (i.e. `Chicago-IL|1`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Chicago-Illinos1';
echo ++$str;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php