# adding an increment to a variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that collects a variable from a database (a code RS000051 for example) I can collect it into an array and echo it to the page.
what I would like to do is collect the result RS000051 and increment it by 1 RS000052 and so on for each new user created and insert it into the database.

```
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
$query1 = "SELECT Barcode from barcode ORDER BY Barcode DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query1);
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$bar = $array["Barcode"];

echo $bar;
```

I have searched google and stack overflow and the suggestion is $bar++ but nothing happens?

Comment: Seriously consider storing the alpha part separate from the numeric part.

Comment: BTW, you just have to call ++ in the variable. Check it out: [https://3v4l.org/dFJQ3](https://3v4l.org/dFJQ3)

Comment: @Strawberry remove the RS at the beginning of the barcode, I guess that could be a way to go?

Comment: Also dup [Increment integer at end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740780/increment-integer-at-end-of-string) in which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8141149/4577762) is pretty much what you want.

Comment: @FirstOne thank you that solved it, I was putting the ++ at the end of the echo instead

Comment: No problems. A note: ++ _after_ the variable is a _Post-increment_, which will first return the original value, then increment it. You can read more about it in [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Comment: What if a user with a faster machine accesses the same script while you're mid-way through?

Comment: @Strawberry my answer to that would be only one operator with add new user privilege can be logged on at a time